# Best way to reload modules that have changed in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Problem: I like keeping ipython notebooks within jupyter clean and putting utility functions in outside file to keep, but calling them from the notebook as needed once written.

The issue is once I move the completed function to an outside file, I have to kill the kernel and re-run everything to import it!

I have tried doing the normal:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: `autoreload` is also broken for me, though I remember it used to work about a year ago (I had a line `!ninja -C module_directory` / `%reload mymodule`. It is currently dysfunctional.

Comment: @lollercoaster How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the magic function `%run <filename>` where you've got your utility functions defined.

I have had great use for this when I'm writing new utility functions and want to test and improve them in a jupyter notebook without restarting the whole thing each time. Check out chapter IPython Magic Commands by Jake VanderPlas for

**Details:**

I've got a file named `utils.py` in a folder named `c:/jupytertest`.

**Utils.py:**

```
import pandas as pd

def framer(df):
    df_out = df['parch'].to_frame()
    return(df_out)
```

And I've got the following in a **jupyter notebook cell**:

```
# standard imports
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:/jupytertest/')

# run / reload utils
%run utils.py

# data
url = "https://raw.github.com/mattdelhey/kaggle-titanic/master/Data/train.csv"
titanic = pd.read_csv(url)

# test reloading of function from utils.py
values = framer(titanic)

print(values.tail(5))
```

Now every time I change `df_out = df['parch'].to_frame()` to `name` or any other column I know exists in the titanic dataset, the only thing I have to do to apply the up-dated function in jupyter is to save `utils.py` and re-run the cell in the notebook.

No kernel-restart in the notebook should be necessary.

Check out [IPython Magic Commands](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.03-magic-commands.html) in the Python Data science Handbook by Jake VanderPlas for even more details.